# Jambavan's composition of slokam on Hanuman

Tags: puranas, hanuman

Jambavan has composed a slokam on Hanuman comprising 12 hymns. It starts with:

> Melai virinjan veeya migai naalir

Any puranic reference for this???

Comment: If the stotra is in Tamil then the stotra itself most probably won't be in the Puranas. But maybe there is a related story.

Comment: why tamil is not an ancient language??? Kambar wrote Ramayanam in Tamil.

Comment: No doubt Tamil is ancient and sacred - I was saying that since the Puranas are Sanskrit scripture it's not probable that they would address Tamil prayers.

Comment: May be in Sanskrit also this may be there--extensive search is required--

Answer (score 2):

I think you're referring to Jāmbavan's motivational speech towards the end of Kiṣkindha kāṇḍa from [Kamba Rāmāyaṇa](https://books.google.com/books?id=EPTcCd32pJIC&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&lpg=PP1&pg=PT220#v=onepage&q&f=false) :

> (He then proceeded to acquaint Vayu's son with his own greatness.)
>
> 'Brahma may die, but you are endless. You are learned and a good
>   speaker. You are fierce enough to frighten Death. You can fight like
>   Siva himself. Neither fire, nor water, nor wind can kill you. Divine
>   weapons cannot destroy you. With one leap, you can jump across this
>   world.
>
> 'You can grow higher than Meru and contract to less than a drop of
>   rain. You can lift the earth and touch the sun with your hand. You can
>   probe the good and bad and advise wisely. You it was that skillfully
>   planned the death of Vali, out to destroy Dharma.
>
> 'You can take on anyone single-handed. With the undiminished might of
>   your shoulders, you can conquer, liberate or kill. When enraged Indra
>   struck you with his bolt, you did not lose even a single hair.
>
> 'Even the three worlds are nothing against you. Your heroic shoulders
>   can shrug them away in an instant. Walking before the sun, dispelling
>   darkness, learnt from him the Sanskrit lore.
>
> 'You are just, you are truthful, you never ever think of the joys of
>   sex. You're well read and know the Vedas by rote. You are eternal.
>
> 'You have given your heart to Rama and therefore know your duty well.
>   If you resolve to do something, I am certain you will do it, whatever
>   the odds.
>
> 'You know that virtue alone stands where others fall. Your
>   righteousness and patience are an example to Indra and other gods. You
>   are the only true pandit, capable of deeds both thoughtful and
>   fruitful. You can get what you want when you want it.
>
> 'You can be compared only with yourself. Go forth and save our lives
>   and add to your glory. Cross the sea, return with news of Sita and
>   with that deed, make Rama cross the Sea of his sorrow. You are the
>   one, the only one, capable of accomplishing this feat,' concluded
>   Jambavan.

You can find the verses in Tamil [here](https://ta.wikisource.org/wiki/%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%AF%E0%AE%A3%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D/%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%9F%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%A8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BE_%E0%AE%95%E0%AE%BE%E0%AE%A3%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D/%E0%AE%AE%E0%AE%AF%E0%AF%87%E0%AE%A8%E0%AF%8D%E0%AE%A4%E0%AE%BF%E0%AE%B0%E0%AE%AA%E0%AF%8D_%E0%AE%AA%E0%AE%9F%E0%AE%B2%E0%AE%AE%E0%AF%8D); English transliteration is below.

> 4719. 'mElai virinjan veeyinum veeyaa mikai naaLeer; noolai nayandhu,
>         nuNNidhu uNarndheer; nuval thakkeer; kaalanum anjum kaai sina
>         moimpeer; katan nindreer; aalam nukarndhaan enna vayap pOr
>         atarkiRpeer;
> 4720. 'veppuRu sen thee, neer, vaLiyaalum viLiyaadheer; seppuRu theyvap pal
>         pataiyaalum sidhaiyaadheer; oppu uRin, oppaar num aladhu illeer;
>         orukaalE kuppuRin, aNtaththu ap puRamEyum kudhikoLveer;
> 4721. 'nallavum ondrO, theeyavum naati, navai theerach chollavum valleer;
>         kaariyam neerE thuNivutreer; vellavum valleer; meeLavum valleer; mital
>         uNtE; kollavum valleer; thOL vali endrum kuRaiyaadheer;
> 4722. 'mEru kirikkum meedhu uRa niRkum peru meyyeer; maari thuLikkum thaarai
>         itukkum, vara valleer; paarai etukkum nOnmai valaththeer; pazhi
>         atreer; sooriyanaich chendru, oN kaiyakaththum thota valleer;
> 4723. 'aRindhu, thiRaththu aaRu eNNi, aRaththu aaRu azhiyaamai maRindhu
>         uruLa, pOr vaaliyai vellum madhi valleer; poRindhu imaiyOr kOn
>         vachchira paaNam puka moozhka eRindhuzhi, matru Or pun mayirEnum
>         izhavaadheer;
> 4724. 'pOrmun edhirndhaal mooulakEnum poruL aakaa; Orvu il valam koNtu, olkal
>         il veeraththu uyar thOLeer; paar ulaku engum pEr iruL seekkum
>         pakalOnmun, thEr mun natandhE, aariya noolum therivutreer;
> 4725. 'needhiyil nindreer; vaaimai amaindheer; ninaivaalum maadhar nalam
>         pENaadhu vaLarndheer; maRai ellaam Odhi uNarndheer; oozhi katandheer;
>         ulaku eenum aadhi ayan thaanE ena yaarum aRaikindreer;
> 4726. 'aNNal a(m)maindharkku anpu siRandheer; adhanaalE kaNNi uNarndheer
>         karumam; numakkE katan ennath thiNNidhu amaindheer; seydhu mutippeer;
>         sidhaivu indraal; puNNiyam ondrE endrum nilaikkum poruL koNteer;
> 4727. 'atangavum valleer; kaalam adhu andrEl; amar vandhaal, matangal
>         munindhaalanna valaththeer; madhi naatith thotangiyadhu ondrO? mutrum
>         mutikkum thozhil allaal, itam keta, vev vaai ooRu kitaiththaal
>         itaiyaadheer;
> 4728. 'eeNtiya kotraththu indhiran enpaan mudhal yaarum pooNtu natakkum nal
>         neRiyaanum poRaiyaanum paaNtidhar neerE; paarththu inidhu uykkumpati
>         valleer; vENtiya pOdhE vENtuva eydhum vinai valleer.
> 4729. 'Ekumin; Eki, em uyir nalki, isai koLLeer; Okai koNarndhu um mannaiyum,
>         innal kuRaivu illaach chaakaram mutrum thaavitum neer, ik katal
>         thaavum vEkam amaindheer!' endru virinjan makan vittaan.